@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function while try parse html in webview
I want to implement a dynamic html page parsing function. The implementation is as follows:
First, I load the page into the WebView, then I parse it. I ran into a problem that when I try to call a @Composable function inside a non-@Composable function, an error occurs. In this case, I'm trying to call the "loadAndParseWebPageComposable" function. How can I get around this error? The module code is shown below.


@Composable
fun AddProductScreen(viewModel: ProductViewModel, onAddComplete: () -> Unit) {
    var url by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var loading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        TextField(
            value = url,
            onValueChange = { url = it },
            label = { Text("Введите URL товара") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = {
            loading = true
        }) {
            Text("Добавить")
        }
        if (loading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }

        if (loading) {
            LaunchedEffect(url) {
                loadAndParseWebPageComposable(url, viewModel) {
                    loading = false
                    onAddComplete()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun loadAndParseWebPageComposable(url: String, viewModel: ProductViewModel, onLoaded: () -> Unit) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(context).apply {
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                    view.evaluateJavascript(
                        "(function() { return document.documentElement.outerHTML })();"
                    ) { html ->
                        viewModel.parseProductHtml(html ?: "")
                        onLoaded()
                    }
                }
            }
            loadUrl(url)
        }
    }, update = { webView ->
        webView.loadUrl(url)
    })
}

I tried to search the Internet for similar situations, but I didn't find anything concrete, and removing the @Composable annotation from the "loadAndParseWebPageComposable" function won't work, since there is an AndroidView inside

Although LaunchedEffect is a composable function, its lambda is not. Therefore no composables can be called here.
There is no reason to even use a LaunchedEffect here, so you can just remove it. loadAndParseWebPageComposable will then be called on every recomposition where either url or viewModel changed (and loading is true, obviously).

It doesn't make any sense to use the LaunchedEffect here. Simply remove it.
if (loading) {
    loadAndParseWebPageComposable(url, viewModel) {
            loading = false
            onAddComplete()
    }
}

